# Css, child-divs and floating

Tags: css, position, html

I'm tired of work with these kinds of divs :(.

I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="row_left"></div>
  <div id="row_middle"></div>
  <div id="row_right"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

css:

```css
#content {
  overflow: hidden; width: 100%;
}
```

Content-div is including another 3 divs, which should stay horizontally.

```css
#row_left, #row_middle, #row_rifht { float: left; width: 33%; }
```

The trouble is that bottom div doesn't stay refer to content-text. It's always on the same position, even when content-rows text is over. How can I repair it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a div after content with the style:

```
clear: both; line-height: 0.1em;
```

And put an

```
&nbsp;
```

in it

Comment: Rippo's answer is more correct... just add "clear: both" to the bottom div as long as the bottom div has content in it.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose it depends on what the author likes!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
...
<div id="bottom" style='clear:both'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to clear the floats without adding extra markup, put this in your CSS:

```
#content { zoom: 1; }
#content:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: ".";
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```